# Terraform Openstack Output parameter for CPU & Memory

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-openstack

Terrafomr OPENSTACK provider, I am unable to find the output parameter for CPU and memory

Example:

```
output "instanceip" 

value = "${openstack_compute_instance_v2.instance.network.0.fixed_ip_v4}"
```

We get IP from above code here I need to get output for CPU & Memory

Comment: Please post your attempt (code) at solving this.

Comment: Moved the code portion of the question into a code block so it would stand out.